# Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-signin

I'm using the google-signin-plugin-1.0.4.unitypackage (https://github.com/googlesamples/google-signin-unity/releases) and am quite about to have an aneurysm.  I'm using the code below and while OnSignIn() is called and at least partially works, OnAuthenticationFinished doesn't seem to be called.  Reading the Errors in logcat, I get the  Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration and 20+ other errors.  My temporary status box tUserWelcome loads "Hello World" and changes to "Init Signin" as expected, but never changes to "Auth Next" hence how I know where it's dying.  With this part failing, I am unable to pull any user data, such as the user's name or e-mail address or token.

Using the Google developer console I've created an Android key with matching package names and SHA-1 keys.  I also tried using a Web key vs an Android key (as suggested on other stackoverflow articles with the same error) but with the same results.

I press the button to call OnSignIn, I select my user account and then nothing.  It seems to somehow staying logged in as I can exit the app and relaunch and don't get prompted to select the account when calling OnSignIn.  I'm using the "Build and Run" option with my phone in USB debugging mode (unsure if this makes a difference or not).

Added note, this was largly copied from the sample scripts in the unity package being slightly modified to match my objects.

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Threading.Tasks;
  using Google;
  using UnityEngine;
  using UnityEngine.UI;

  public class LoginControl : MonoBehaviour {

   // public Text statusText;
    public Text tUserWelcome;

    public string webClientId = "<your client id here>";

    private GoogleSignInConfiguration configuration;

      void Awake() {
    //statusText.text = "";
    configuration = new GoogleSignInConfiguration {
    WebClientId = webClientId,
    RequestIdToken = true
        };
    tUserWelcome.text = "Hello World";
      }
    public void OnSignIn() {
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
        GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
        tUserWelcome.text = "Init SignIn";
        //AddStatusText("Calling SignIn");
        GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(
          OnAuthenticationFinished);
    }
    
    internal void OnAuthenticationFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task) {
        tUserWelcome.text = "Auth Next";
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            using (IEnumerator<System.Exception> enumerator =
              task.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator()) {
                if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                    GoogleSignIn.SignInException error = (GoogleSignIn.SignInException)enumerator.Current;
                    tUserWelcome.text = error.Status.ToString();
                    //AddStatusText("Got Error: " + error.Status + " " + error.Message);
                } else {
                //  AddStatusText("Got Unexpected Exception?!?" + task.Exception);
                }
                tUserWelcome.text = task.Exception.ToString();
            }
        } else if(task.IsCanceled) {
        //  AddStatusText("Canceled");
            tUserWelcome.text = "Cancled?";
        } else{
            //AddStatusText("Welcome: " + task.Result.DisplayName + "!");
            tUserWelcome.text = "Welcome " + task.Result.DisplayName;
        }
        tUserWelcome.text = "do WHA?";
    }
```

Here is a complete stack trace from logcat.

```
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  : Class not found when unmarshalling: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:3031)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2981)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2883)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3261)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:1160)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:8552)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:847)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:732)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:2072)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at com.android.server.wm.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:646)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1717)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1613)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivity(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:1566)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityTaskManager.java:1737)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1056)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1029)
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  : Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInConfiguration
10-15 22:49:06.082  1240  1265 E Parcel  :      ... 20 more
```

This is really driving me batty so any help ya'll could lend would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the error message being logged seems to be a Samsung specific error and does not seem to affect how the code is running.

The whole time login *HAS* been working, but due to who knows what reason (likely a behavior change) to get the message box (e.g. username) to work correctly, I needed to add TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously to ensure GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn() completed prior to trying to pull user data.  I'll be opening a issue on the github project.

```
public void OnSignIn() {
    GoogleSignIn.Configuration = configuration;
    GoogleSignIn.Configuration.UseGameSignIn = false;
    GoogleSignIn.Configuration.RequestIdToken = true;
    tUserWelcome.text = "Init SignIn";
    //AddStatusText("Calling SignIn");
    tUserWelcome.text = webClientId;
    GoogleSignIn.DefaultInstance.SignIn().ContinueWith(
      OnAuthenticationFinished, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
}

internal void OnAuthenticationFinished(Task<GoogleSignInUser> task) {
    tUserWelcome.text = "Auth Next";
    if (task.IsFaulted) {
        using (IEnumerator<System.Exception> enumerator =
          task.Exception.InnerExceptions.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                GoogleSignIn.SignInException error = (GoogleSignIn.SignInException)enumerator.Current;
                tUserWelcome.text = "error";
                //AddStatusText("Got Error: " + error.Status + " " + error.Message);
            } else {
            //  AddStatusText("Got Unexpected Exception?!?" + task.Exception);
                tUserWelcome.text = "Unexpected";
            }
            tUserWelcome.text = "Exception";
        }
    } else if(task.IsCanceled) {
    //  AddStatusText("Canceled");
        tUserWelcome.text = "Cancled?";
    } else{
        //AddStatusText("Welcome: " + task.Result.DisplayName + "!");
        tUserWelcome.text = "Welcome " + task.Result.DisplayName;
    }
}
```